# Downward Double-Vision

Tags: eye, vision, aging, double-vision

If I focus on the ring in this image (the ring is 1 cm tall on my monitor,
I stand 300 cm away, the room is dark, and I cover one eye), I actually
see an "8" formed from double-vision where the lower ring is dimmer.  So,
I'd simply say that this lower ring is caused by a cataract.

To be honest, the "cataract ring" is not just lower, but also slightly right;
the off-vertical angle is roughly 20 degrees.  It's interesting that my other
eye also has similar downward double-vision (with a smaller 10 degree
rightward shift).  (I get even more cataract glare details when I focus on the
small dot to the left, instead of the ring, but I'm trying to keep this question
simple.)

Do most people have downward double-vision in both eyes like me?  If so, is
there any theory about why/how the eye changes asymmetrically as we age?
I guess that the exact statistical study I'm suggesting here has never been
done, but hope cataracts have been studied enough to answer theoretically.

[image]